# creating view of three tables with their id connections on seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have some tables.
City:

```
CI_ID | City
1     | Aberdeen
2     | Abingdon
```

Country:

```
CO_ID | Country
1     | United States of America
2     | Australia
```

Province:

```
PR_ID | Province
1     | Alabama
2     | South Dakota
```

City_Province

```
CI_ID | PR_ID
1     | 2
2     | NULL
```

City_Country

```
CI_ID | CO_ID
1     | 1
2     | 2
```

And by creating view I want to have

```
CI_ID | City     | Province     | Country
1     | Aberdeen | South Dakota | United States of America
2     | Abingdon | NULL         | Australia
```

And I can't figure out the query.

Comment: ummm, if province == state, australia has between 6 and 9 (depending on the definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the five tables, but `LEFT JOIN` the `Province` table like this:

**Create View:**

```
CREATE VIEW AllData
AS
SELECT
  c.CI_ID, 
  c.city,
  p.Province,
  co.Country     
FROM City c
INNER JOIN City_Province cp ON c.CI_ID = cp.CI_ID
INNER JOIN City_Country cc ON cc.CI_ID = c.CI_ID
INNER JOIN Country co ON cc.CO_ID = co.CO_ID 
LEFT JOIN Province p ON p.PR_ID  = cp.PR_ID;
```

Then, whenever you want to select from that view, you can select from it just like a normal table:

```
SELECT * FROM AllData
```

This will give you:

```
| CI_ID |     CITY |     PROVINCE |                  COUNTRY |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 | Aberdeen | South Dakota | United States of America |
|     2 | Abingdon |       (null) |                Australia |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7f61/1)

For more information:

- [Mysql Reference: **13.1.12. CREATE VIEW Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)
- [**Join (SQL)<sup>From Wikipedia</sup>**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Another Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).